# Dynamic Table name in SQL Server T-SQL query without "EXECUTE sp_executesql" etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Isn't there really any other solution to that problem?
"sp_executesql" etc. things look to me quite old-school in these days.

Comment: Another way is using `EXEC('select...'+@tablename)`. Or you can use `IF` condition if the tables are predefined set

Comment: What's the problem with `sp_executesql`? If you want dynamic sql, you need to use it, how else would you execute your generated statement?

Comment: Change the way you look at things.  `sp_executesql` is the right way to execute dynamic SQL.

Comment: IF is not the options as the tables are not predefined. And sp_execute/dynamic SQL costs performance. the only dynamic part in our queries is the table name, so i just wonder if new SQL servers do not have any support for this. Obviously they don't.

Comment: Having a variable table name necessitates Dynamic SQL. And that's that. Regular SQL does not allow for variable table names, same for database name, schema name, operators, functions and so on.

Comment: The reason performance takes a hit is because SQL Server doesn't know what is coming and therefore can't prepare as well as a normal stored proc etc.  If you have dynamic table names, you have dynamic SQL and you are going to hit the problems associated.  What is it you are trying to achieve that you think could be accomplished without dynamic SQL?

Comment: You can use `sp_MSforeachtable`. But is undocumented.

Comment: Like iamdave more or less said, the query optimizer can't generate a plan when the tables are not static. It needs to know what table it's looking at to figure out the best way to execute the query.
If your tables are so similar in structure, why can't they be normalized into 1 table with another column that would indicate which table they would go into?
If that's not possible, you could try to UNION ALL the tables involved but add a where clause to each so that only the table you wanted would return data & all the rest would return an empty set.
Something like WHERE (1=1) vs WHERE (1=0).

Comment: To be honest: if you regularly have the situation that you don't know what the name of your table is, I would question your deployment or development process. I have hardly ever seen any environment where a big part of the code uses dynamic SQL (let alone inside stored procedures)

Comment: Guys, I completely agree. I;m not DBA in company I work for and i dont like the way they do this. I hate dynamic SQL and this idea with creating tables with dynamic names is a bad idea. It is in place for 11 years now. Time to change it. I just wanted to double check I'm not crazy when saying so.

Comment: Anyways, I think, theoretically, if the the only dynamic part of your query is a name of a table, where the table is always the same(schema), then SQL could use execution plans etc. But the think is how to tell that to SQL engine. I can imagine a new SQL clause or similar: SELECT Id, Name From TABLE<MyTable>("myTable" + suffix) Where Id > 30; By Using MyTable as a template the SQL could get the table schema details, template would be a new SQL type.